# heroku keeps installing django packages during each deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

Im using django 3 and Python 3.7.4
I don't have any issues with the deployment and the project is working, it's just the first time I face this issue.
Normally when deploying to Heroku all packages in the requirements file get installed during the first deployment process, and any further deployment will only update or install the new packages the get added.

In my case, everytime I deploy, heroku is installing the whole packages again.

Please advise if there is a way to handle this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a current issue with the [Heroku python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python). As long as the issue persists the cache is cleared on every build, since the [sqlite3 check is broken](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/909). Suggest upvoting the issue on GitHub.